# browserify Using JQuery globally and in Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I have been given a template to work from by a client that has some 28 different jquery plugins that the client wants to use (e.g. ditching them not an option).

However I really want to use browserify to modularise my code, but short of trying to shim all 28 plugin and thir dependancy I can't work out how I would do that and not have to load JQuery for browserify and globally.

I tried doing this:

```
window.JQuery = require('jquery')
window.$ = window.JQuery
```

And this:

```
var globals = function(){
  window.JQuery = require('jquery')
  window.$ = window.JQuery
}

globals();
```

But neither seem to work and all the plugins throw an error.  Does anyone now how I might make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty good way to do it, I think.

1. npm install jquery
2. npm install browserify-shim
3. Put this line in your package.json:

   ```
   browserify-shim" : {
     "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" : "$"
   }
   ```

So on the server, your usual `require('jquery')` will point to the node_modules spot. When you run browserify, it will set `window.$` to the same code (you could also use `jQuery`). Also, if you did want to shim those plugins, just add them like this:

```
    "browserify-shim" : {
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" : "jQuery",
      "./plugins/bs_modal.js" :  { 
        "depends": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" ] 
      }
    }
```

or, cleaner:

```
    "browser" : {"jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"},
    "browserify-shim" : {
      "jquery" : "jQuery",
      "./plugins/bs_modal.js" :  { 
        "depends": [ "jquery" ] 
      }
    }
```

Comment: And now how to use bs_modal.js plugin in for example Backbone.View  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the line below, to get bootstrap and jquery to be browserified:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: This is sort of the other way around. You are exposing internal jQuery to your window, instead of requiring window.jQuery inside your browserify world.